# DIG: always get a status: FORMERR

Tags: domain-name-system, dig

I'm under ubuntu 18.04, having DNS issues, so I am using `dig` command to debug my DNS.

Thing is when I dig a site like `redhat.com`, or a well configured DNS of mine, I always get a `FORMERR` status, and it appears that `SERVER` is always set to 127.0.0.1:53.

```
➜  dig redhat.com                            

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.5-Ubuntu <<>> redhat.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: FORMERR, id: 14902
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: 0929f0a01195f776 (echoed)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;redhat.com.            IN  A

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Mar 19 11:17:10 CET 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 51
```

Answer (score 6):

I fixed it adding `+noedns` to the command:

```
$ dig +noedns redhat.com  

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.5-Ubuntu <<>> +noedns redhat.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 47501
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;redhat.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
redhat.com.     522 IN  A   209.132.183.105

;; Query time: 51 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Mar 19 13:51:28 CET 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 44
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: That means your server has serious problems to fix. Have a look at https://dnsflagday.net/ and it is probably time for an upgrade.

Comment: when you tell my server, is it DnsMasq ? I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with nothing custom